# Why is this django test is failing?

Tags: python, django, testing, url

Whenever I run my *test.py* I get:

> (blog-1rz6wx-6) λ python manage.py test Creating test database for
> alias 'default'... System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
> .F..
> ====================================================================== FAIL: test_post_detail_view (blog.tests.BlogTests)
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\ **** \Desktop\blog\blog\tests.py", line 40, in
> test_post_detail_view
> self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
> AssertionError: 404 != 200
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 4 tests in 0.776s
>
> FAILED (failures=1) Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

My *test.py* code:

```
def test_post_detail_view(self):
    response = self.client.get('/post/1/')
    no_response = self.client.get('/post/100000')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertEqual(no_response.status_code, 404)
    self.assertContains(response, 'A good title')
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'post_detail.html')
```

*urls.py* that is in the same folder as *settings.py:*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('blog.urls')),
]
```

And the *urls.py* that is located in the same folder as views.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import BlogListView, BlogDetailView
urlpatterns = [
  path('post/<int:pk>', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name = 'post_detail'),
        path('',BlogListView.as_view(),name = 'home')
    ]
```

I have no Idea, and when I changed the response to `response = self.client.get('')`, it does come up with code 200, but the TemplateUsed obviously becomes *'home.html*.

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that the `/post/1/` endpoint doesn't exist. You might want to try eliminating the final `/` along with making sure your fixture is resulting in a post with that id being created.

Comment: Thanks! this solved the issue, oh god I was dealing with this for about 2 hours. Thank you very much, feel so dumb rn lmao

Answer (score 1):

I look like you are passing post id in URL `/post/1/` but when you run the test in Django it creates a separate DB. To run the test successfully you need to define `def setUp(self):` and create a post to run the test successfully.

Comment: Ok so my *setUp* goes like this:
`def setUp(self):
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            username = 'testuser',
            email = 'test@email.com',
            password = 'secret'
        )

        self.post = Post.objects.create(
            title = 'A good title',
            body = 'Nice body content',
            author = self.user,
        )`

Comment: Ok, @hd1 already helped me fix this issue, thank you very much.